# Vertical scrolling news stuck on time delay "WP News and Scrolling Widgets" wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website www.docmbbs.com . In vertical news section, scrolling is not proper. After timedelay there is a stuck in every news.I am using "WP News and Scrolling Widgets" plugin. But on http://demo.wponlinesupport.com/sp-news/ Its working nice in sidebar. Please help me to fix this bug. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add some screenshots and detail your exact deployment?

Comment: Hi  Frank Yucheng Gu, yoc can not understand by screenshot. Please visit https://docmbbs.com/ and see scrolling news below slider. There is a jerking in news slide.

See Demo in sidebar  http://demo.wponlinesupport.com/sp-news/

Comment: put what you mentioned here in the comments in your question. It will improve the quality of the question and more people will be able to help you in the future. But I'm glad that you solved it and posted the solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved. It was due to some padding issue.
I try this one and solved.
.news_li {padding-bottom: 0 !important;}
.news_li a.newspost-title {padding-bottom:10px !important;}